# Incremento do número da versão

Tags: android-studio, versionamento

Gostaria de opinião e ajuda para o número da versão 1.0.0.1(exemplo).

Como posso fazer de forma simples este incremento ficar automático?
Ou mais, como é normalmente ou de boa prática, incrementar este número antes e após os "pontos"?

Obrigado!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377655/code-version-change-rules/3377717#3377717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu adiciono um campo na tela que quero mostrar a versão e alimento esse campo 
do seguinte modo:

```
  Date buildDate = new Date(BuildConfig.TIMESTAMP);
  idversion.setText("Versão: " + buildDate.toString());
```

Claro, você pode formata-lo como quiser com base na data atual.